# What is the correct way to use "Hands Down" in a sentence, grammar-wise?

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, expressions, sentence

What is the correct option\s in this case?

- Hands down, the best value for your money!
- Hands down, get best value for your money!
- It's hands down the best value for your money!
- The best value for your money, hands down!
- Get the best value for your money, hands down!
- Best value for your money hands down!

Thank you

Comment: "hands down" means "without a doubt".  By subsituting that in, you'll have sentences which are idiom-free and much easier to apply the standard rules of grammar to.  This should enable you to see which ones work and which don't.

Comment: Try looking in a dictionary first - see [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hands-down) and [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hands-down?q=hands+down), and other online dictionaries.  Then come back with any questions arising from what you found. [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may suit you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Hands down' is an adverbial phrase, so it can be used anywhere that an adverb can.

You should probably note that of your example phrases only the third and fifth are strictly correct grammatical sentences, even if you substituted 'hands down' with another adverb. Numbers 1, 4 and 5 are contractions, with an implicit 'it is' or 'it is the' at the start. Contractions like this are best not used in formal writing, but acceptable informally.

Sentence 2 is problematic. It's grammatically correct, but means something different from the others. Most speakers would take "Get the best value for your money" as an imperative, and understand an adverb before it as modifying that clause. So the meaning would be "Without a doubt [you should] get the best value for your money".